# highcharts - log axis not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a high chart code like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('linechart', {

  chart: {
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
        borderRadius:5,
    },

    title: {
        text: 'ROC Graph'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Learning Evaluation'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        tickWidth:1,
        tickPositions: [0.001, 0.01, 0.1,1]
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 1,
        tickInterval:0.1,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0.30
        }
    },



});
```

And my javascript code:

```
for(j=0; j<data.roc_buffer[i]['xs'].length/10;j++){
      x_plot = data.roc_buffer[i]['xs'][10*j]
      y_plot = data.roc_buffer[i]['ys'][10*j]
      plot_buffer[j] = {'x':x_plot, 'y':y_plot}                  
 }
 roc_chart.addSeries({
     name: data.roc_buffer[i]['plotname'],
     data: plot_buffer

  });
```

It work out fine like this
[image]

However, I want the [0.001,0.01,0.1,1] all have same width so I need to adjust the xaxis to type logarithm. So I switch my code to:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
    },
```

Now the line disappear...

Also my data is something like

```
[{x:integer,y:integer},{x:integer,y:integer},{x:integer,y:integer},...]
```

Comment: This code is not complete. Instead of pasting how you create the data, paste sample of the data - so the issue can be fully reproduced.

Comment: the samples of data is just like the above.

Comment: a list of {x:integer,y:integer} pair. and the list is the input data for the "data" parameter.

Comment: @morganfree do you any idea. really need help right here!

Comment: You receive the error in the console - http://www.highcharts.com/errors/10 -  you cannot have xAxis min set to 0 in logarithmic axis.

Comment: i did remove it. `xAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
    },` this the final version

Answer (score 0):

**What I understand.**

Your xAxis and yAxis both value dynamically generated.

You can set data using setData method for yAxis and setCategories for xAxis.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
highchart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 4, 8, 16]);
highchart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M']);});
```

or Check jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/ashish8833/w3o0jzL7/1/

Comment: You probably miss understand my question. I want my xaxis to be `[0.001,0.01,0.1,1]` (no change) but i want the tick width be the same.(so the step between (0.1,1) and (0.01,0.1)should be same. Thanks!